# Unable to load file from resources, path seems to be wrong

Tags: java, maven, file, spring-mvc, path

I got the folders services and webapp on the same level.
Inside services I have the file MailServiceImpl.java.
Inside I got this:

```
@Override
public String getHTML() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    File initialFile = new File("../webapp/src/main/webapp/resources/html/Mail.html");
    InputStream targetStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(initialFile);
    String htmlFile = IOUtils.toString(targetStream);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(targetStream);
    return htmlFile;
}
```

Now the path seems to be failing in the deployed version of my application. Any ideas how to make this path relative?
The path works fine on my computer.

Here's how my folders look:

[image]

[image]

Comment: After you have deployed you code (somewhere) then you do not have the same access to the source code (it is not deployed) - try moving to src/main/resources

Comment: I don't know why but I've tried moving Mail.html to the services folder and changing the path to "Mail.html" and it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: When compile and pack your app your file will be in **/resources/html/Mail.html**. Try to use the absolute path to create the file.